# Match a given regex except if a given word exist (lookahead or lookbehind)

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I am using javascript regex to parse a series of URLs. I need to match a digit in a URL (it's actually more complicated, but I'm simplifying), but only want to match a number where a given word is not in the URL.

Namely, I want to exclude lines with the word 'changelogs' in them, and would therefore capture '**1047**', '**1048**', '**1245**' and '**1049**' from the following list;

```
http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/unified/1215/
http://www.whatever.com/docs/changelogs/anythingelse/anything/1215/
http://www.blabblah/security/advisory/1047
http://booger/security/advisory/1048/
ftp://msn.global.whatever/somethingelse/1245
whatever/it/doesnt/matter/could/be/anything/i/still/want/this/number/1049/
```

I know I need some kind of look-around look-ahead look-behind, but I'm striking out. Here is the last pattern I've tried;

```
(?!changelogs)(\d+)
```

[Here is the regex101 sandbox I'm using](https://regex101.com/r/tC7tA7/1).

**Also, it's important that the only match is the actual number. I don't want anything else to match**.

---

Here is what my .NET code looks like (note the "BulletinOrAdvisoryPattern" is the regex in question)...

```
Regex bulletinPattern = new Regex(@matchingDomain.Vendor.BulletinOrAdvisoryPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase );
Match bulletinMatch = bulletinPattern.Match(referenceTitle);

                    if (bulletinMatch.Success)
                    {
                        //Found the bulletin ID in the NVD Reference Title 
                        return bulletinMatch.Value;
                    }
```

Comment: Does it mean you do not know how to access `Match.Groups[1].Value`? Also, you do not need a regex for this. Why use regex? Besides, why use regex101 that only supports Python/PCRE/JS if you need a .NET regex?

Comment: JavaScript does not have a lookbehind. You *MUST* use a consuming pattern like [`^(?!.*\/changelogs(?:\/|$)).*\/(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/vZ2eL7/1). The requirement *Also, it's important that the only match is the actual number. I don't want anything else to match.* makes this question unclear and impossible to answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please see my edit to see what I mean. Currently all my regex for pattern matching, matches explicitly what I need (for example, I may have a regex with the word "duck" and the "return bulletinmatch.value" will return the exact match duck , or I may have a regex that matches on digits, and the line "return bulletinmatch.value" will return only that digit. I'd rather not have to specify a Group because that group would be different for every domain im matching against. Does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense, and means that you need to change that method to return a specific group. Since the match value is always Group 0, you can specify the `0` argument to get the match.value, and `1` to get the first captured value, `2` for the second, and so on. You can't do that anoher way in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ugly" regex you need is

```
(?<=http://www\.opera\.com\b(?!.*/changelogs(?:/|$))\S*)\d+
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww%5C.opera%5C.com%5Cb(%3F!.*%2Fchangelogs(%3F%3A%2F%7C%5Cr%3F%24))%5CS*)%5Cd%2B&i=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opera.com%2Fdocs%2Fchangelogs%2Funified%2F1215%2F%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.opera.com%2Fdocs%2Fchangelogs%2Fanythingelse%2Fanything%2F1215%2F%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.opera.com%2Fsecurity%2Fadvisory%2F1047%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.opera.com%2Fsecurity%2Fadvisory%2F1048%2F%0D%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.opera.com%2Fdoesnt%2Fmatter%2Fcould%2Fbe%2Fanything%2F1049%2F&o=m)

However, all you need is

```
var result = input.Contains("/changelogs/") ? "" : input.Trim('/').Split('/').LastOrDefault();
```

See the [IDEONE C# demo](http://ideone.com/GvsoA8):

```
var lst = new List<string>() {"http://w...content-available-to-author-only...a.com/docs/changelogs/unified/1215/",
    "http://w...content-available-to-author-only...a.com/docs/changelogs/anythingelse/anything/1215/",
    "http://w...content-available-to-author-only...a.com/security/advisory/1047",
    "http://w...content-available-to-author-only...a.com/security/advisory/1048/",
    "http://w...content-available-to-author-only...a.com/doesnt/matter/could/be/anything/1049/"};
lst.ForEach(m => Console.WriteLine(
        m.Contains("/changelogs/") ? "" : m.Trim('/').Split('/').LastOrDefault()
    ));
```

**UPDATE**

You switched the language from C# to JavaScript that changes the situation drastically since JS regex engine does not support a lookbehind.

Thus, you have to work around it, and there are means to mimick the lookbehind, or just use capturing mechanism.

If you can use *capturing*, try

```
/^(?!.*\/changelogs(?:\/|$)).*\/(\d+)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vZ2eL7/1)

```js
var re = /^(?!.*\/changelogs(?:\/|$)).*\/(\d+)/gmi; 
var str = 'http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/unified/1215/\nhttp://www.whatever.com/docs/changelogs/anythingelse/anything/1215/\nhttp://www.blabblah/security/advisory/1047\nhttp://booger/security/advisory/1048/\nftp://msn.global.whatever/somethingelse/1245\nwhatever/it/doesnt/matter/could/be/anything/i/still/want/this/number/1049/';
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4);
```

Or, use an optional group (if you are replacing):

```js
var re = /(\/changelogs\/.*)?\/(\d+)/gi; 
var str = 'http://www.opera.com/docs/changelogs/unified/1215/\nhttp://www.whatever.com/docs/changelogs/anythingelse/anything/1215/\nhttp://www.blabblah/security/advisory/1047\nhttp://booger/security/advisory/1048/\nftp://msn.global.whatever/somethingelse/1245\nwhatever/it/doesnt/matter/could/be/anything/i/still/want/this/number/1049/';
var result = str.replace(re, function (m, g1, g2){
  return g1 ? m : "NEW_VAL";
});
document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Answer (score 1):

something like the below should do it. If you are not only interested in opera, you would be able to tweak this to be more general by replacing opera with `.+` Additionally you could match things like com and net with something like `(com|net|org|gov)` in place of com:

```
http:\/\/www\.opera\.com(?!.*changelogs)(\/[^\/]+)*\/(\d+)\/{0,1}
```

[Here is your regex 101 updated to reflect this](https://regex101.com/r/tC7tA7/2)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Indeed, i dont care about the domain part (first half). I tried replacing the first half with .+ but then it matches on every line. Instead I changed it to match on backslash. https://regex101.com/r/tC7tA7/6 anyway to get it to not care what comes before changelogs?

Answer (score 1):

This pattern excludes lines with 'changelogs' in them and finds the last occurrence of a number encapsulated by slashes.

```
(?:\/)(?!.*changelogs)(?:\/[^\/]+)*\/(\d+)\/{0,1}
```

Here is the [updated regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/tC7tA7/6).

Comment: Thanks but only the digit/number should match. This is returning two matches per line